# How to position your iframe to be below than others(side by side)?

Tags: html, iframe, bootstrap-4

I am struggling to have the last iframe to be below than those two iframes, In another words the two must remain there as normal. While the last iframe should below by having the switch button inside it.

```
<!---iframes for both temp, illuminance and button-state.
  --->
  <br/>
  <div class = "box">
  <iframe src="https://thingspeak.com/channels/929272/charts/1?bgcolor=%23ffffff&color=%23d62020&dynamic=true&results=60&type=line&update=15" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="250" align="left">
  </iframe>
  </div>

<div class="box">
<iframe src="https://thingspeak.com/channels/929272/charts/2?bgcolor=%23ffffff&color=%23d62020&dynamic=true&results=60&type=line&update=15" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="250" align="right">
</iframe>
</div>
  <br/>
 <div class = "row">
 <div class = "col-md-4">
 <div class = "iframe-container">
<iframe  src="https://thingspeak.com/channels/929272/charts/8?bgcolor=%23ffffff&color=%23d62020&dynamic=true&results=60&type=line&update=15" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="250" align = "middle">
 </iframe>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
<div class="clear">
  </div>

   <!----Toggle button for switching On/Off when is clicked.
  ---->
  <div class = "wrapper" align = "center">
  <div class="btn-group" id="toggle_event_editing">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger locked_active">OFF</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success unlocked_inactive">ON</button>
</div> 
<div class="alert alert-info" id="switch_status">Switched off.</div>
  </div>
 <br/>
  <!---DatePicker for startDate and endDate.
   ----> 
   <div class="d-flex justify-content-start">
   <div class = "col-xl-10.5 col-lg-10.5 col-md-10 col-sm-10.5 col-10.5">
 <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
   <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" id="startdate" placeholder="startdate"/>
   <span class="input-group-addon">To</span>
   <input type="text" class= "input-sm form-control"id ="enddate" placeholder="enddate"/>
     </div>
     </div>
  </div><br>
<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it, see my demonstration below that is my last iframe should be.

```
 <br/>
  <div class="frame-wrap">
   <iframe src="https://thingspeak.com/channels/929272/charts/8?bgcolor=%23ffffff&color=%23d62020&dynamic=true&results=60&type=line&update=15" class="frame2" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="250">
   </iframe>
 <!----Toggle button for switching On/Off when is clicked.
  ---->
  <div class = "wrapper" align = "center">
  <div class="btn-group" id="toggle_event_editing">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger locked_active">OFF</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success unlocked_inactive">ON</button>
</div> 
<div class="alert alert-info" id="switch_status">Switched off.</div>
  </div>
 <br/>

  .frame2 {
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```